# Classifier for weighted class label

Tags: classification, cart, weights

Is there any rule-based classifier which be able to classify samples with weighted class labels. In other word, different confidence in tagging samples.

My problem deals with learning samples from one class with difference confidence in belonging to that class.

Answer (score 1):

R provides ctree. Ctree builds a decision tree with the option of specifying weights that give more or less importance to the misclassification of cases. For an example see: https://heuristically.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/weighting-model-fit-ctree-party/